# Find and exec - escaping to prevent problems with $ and ` in filenames?

Tags: bash, escaping

I am running the following bash script to find and execute an ID3 modification command on all the .mp3 files in my folders

```
find -name "*.mp3" -exec bash -c 'eyeD3 --to-v1.1 "{}"' \;
```

It fails on filenames that contain dollar signs and backticks

```
bash: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching ``'
bash: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

filenames that fail are eg.

```
08 - Sam Smith - I'm Not The Only One (Feat. A$AP Rocky).mp3 
02 - The Vaccines - Wreckin` Bar (Ra Ra Ra).mp3
```

I know these are special characters so need escaping - but how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need Bash there.

```
find -name '*.mp3' -exec eyeD3 --to-v1.1 {} +
```

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you have some characters in file that change character of your command/parameters. Might be that your filename is not recognized as you thought it would be. Remeber: in linux shell problems with spces/special characters never end.
Therefore it would be easier to do it in safer way:

```
find -name "*.mp3" -print0 | xargs -n 1 -0 eyeD3 --to-v1.1
```